# JDK 8 not available in classpath

Tags: java

I  have Java 7  in my machine from a long time .And now I have installed Java 8 too .The problem is even after changing the JAVA_HOME & path variable  to point to  jdk 8,  I still get jdk 7 in the classpath.

Snapshot of the environment variables below

But I get the below when checking the version in windows.Is there anything else I should do to get it pointed to jdk8?

```
C:\Users>java -version
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
```

Snapshot of the environment variables below

[image]

Comment: are you changing overall system variables or user system variables ? cause the screenshot you shared , suggests that there is a user variable defined already for that user

Comment: I haven't had to update any of these system properties in more than  15 years. Just let the Java installer do its work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `java.exe, Javac.exe and javaw.exe` from system32
2. Remove `oraclePath` like some text in path of system variable(from jdk8 it will create a new system variable when installing)

Comment: Removed the java.exe & javaw.exe from System 32.Its working now:)Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Four things that come to mind:

1. You seem to have edited the user variables. Have you looked at the system variables? I would prefer to set the `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` variables at system level.
2. Have you restarted cmd/Windows?
3. You could type `where java` in your cmd to see where Windows finds Java(s).
4. What is your `PATH` variable? Looking at your snapshot I it to contain at least `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in your System variables that in the PATH variable, there is no path to your JDK 7?

Even if you define or override a Path variable in the "user" variables, Windows just concatenate the system variables with the user ones, in this order.

So if there is a path to your JDK 7 in System path, you will have this kind of value :
PATH=;.....;D:\java\jdk8;%MAVEN_HOME%

Answer (score 0):

Go in control panel and type java in the search box type java. Click on the link on the java label. Then click on tab java. You will see the active runtimes. Untick the one you don't need.